# Self Updating Exe par on Windows

Tags: windows, perl, par

I am trying to create a script that will "self update" when it detects a new version on a server. Initially the idea I had was, when a new version is detected, download the file, then starts a DOS batch file that simply overwrites the original exe with the new one. I thought, that I could use sytem(start update.bat ) then immediately exit 0; The .bat file waits for a couple seconds, and then tries to delete the old exe. This fails, I guess because even when using system(start ... ), the new "process" is actually the same process, is this correct? Is there any way to launch a completely new process from perl in windows, that would allow me to delete the .exe? Or is there a different approach that would be better?

Thanks,
Eric Seifert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the documentation on the Windows [Restart Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc948910%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), an API introduced with Windows Vista that manages restarting applications, for updates, for you.

Comment: Unfortunately this is an XP environment I have to deal with... But that sounds just like what I would need.

Comment: If you can't use Restart Manager, there are many hacky techniques for self-deleting executables.  http://catch22.net/tuts/selfdel

Comment: Thanks Adrian, that article mentioned the exact technique I described above, using the batch file. Using the ShellExecute command from Win32::FileOp allowed me to run it in the way I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Ever heard of java WebStart? There is a PAR equivalent, PAR::WebStart
Basically, you configure it, then download code live from a trusted website

so your .exe would just be a frontend to PAR::WebStart, with the real program downloaded off your website

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I thought I'd put my solution here since I'm working on the same sort of thing.  Your batch idea is the way I went, but the small change I made was to use `exec()` instead of `system()` since the former (according to [this](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exec.html)) "...executes a system command *and never returns*", which seems to release the running process.  This appears to work both when running interpreted Perl files with Strawberry Perl, and when running compiled programs with `PAR::Packer`.

I've created `test.pl`, which was ultimately compiled to `test.exe`, as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use 5.10.0;
use strict;
use warnings;

    my $batch_file = <<"BATCH";
rem ### IT IS SAFE TO DELETE THIS FILE ###

\@echo off
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 2 -w 1000 > nul
echo Copying over update file...
copy testfile.exe test.exe

BATCH

    open my $fh, '>', 'update.bat';
    print $fh $batch_file;
    close $fh;

    exec( 'update.bat' );
```

`testfile.exe` is a standby "upgraded" version of `test.exe`, just to make sure that I can overwrite `test.exe` while it's running, and I can.  The `ping` is a way to pause for 2 seconds to make sure the process has had a chance to exit before trying to overwrite the file.

Oddly enough, the created batch file `update.bat` can't delete itself, even though batch files can normally delete themselves.  If I create a batch file with this:

```
start /b "" cmd /c del %0
```

It will delete itself without any errors.  But if I include that snippet in `update.bat`, it complains that `The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.`  I'm not sure why.  Since this isn't particularly important in my application, I haven't pursued this.  I just leave `update.bat` behind and let it be overwritten next time an update occurs.  But I do notate in the file that it's safe to delete in case anyone looks at it later.